# How to configure reverse proxy on Apache

Tags: apache

I am planning to forward "/app" from one apache server instance(d1) to another apache instance(d2) where real application is running. The application is a PHP app.

But I am not able to make it work.

Below is the config which I am using.

```
<VirtualHost d1:80>

    ProxyBadHeader Ignore
    ProxyRequests Off
    # ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On 

    ProxyPass /app/ http://d2/app

    <Location /app/>
        ProxyPassReverse  http://d2/app
        RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
    </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

So when I type "ip1/app" in browser it comes up an says "ip1/app//" does not exist. Did anybody have similar issues?

Comment: Did something go wrong in pasting that configuration? Because I struggle with what `ProxyPass /app/ http // d 2/ app` is supposed to mean, there seems to be a lot of whitespace that should be something else...

Comment: yes the site did  not allow me to paste the url. it is actually [link](proxypass /app/ http://d2/app)

Comment: Any change when <VirtualHost d1:80> changed with <VirtualHost *:80> or <VirtualHost ip1:80> ?